# Pixelated endroid emulator on retina screen

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, retina-display

I have some troubles with the android emulator of Android Studio on my macbook pro retina. When I launch it, it is very pixelated. Like on this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTKTi.png

I tried to change the emulation option from "Use Host GPU" to "Snapshot". But it didn't solve my problem.

Do you have any suggestions which could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use some program like  [Retina DisplayMenu v0.2](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/87351306/RDM.tar.gz) 
 as a temporary workaround. You can set the resolution of your choice and won't be irritated by the 'Best for Retina' resolutions (HiDPI ones).